# Tagging a consecutive pattern using VBA /SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'd like to create a report that finds consecutive patterns of records.

Here's a sampling of some of the patterns:

```
1NLUO0  1NM4OM  1NM5AF  1NM5AM  1NM5B1
1NLUO1  1NM4ON  1NM5AG  1NM5AN  1NM5B2
1NLUO2  1NM4OO      1NM5AO  1NM5B3
1NLUO3          1NM5AP  
1NLUO4          1NM5AQ  
1NLUO5          1NM5AR  
1NLUO6          1NM5AS  
1NLUO7          1NM5AT  
1NLUO8          1NM5AU  
1NLUO9          1NM5AW  
            1NM5AX  
            1NM5AY  
            1NM5AZ
```

If there are 2 or more, we would like to group and report them. If it only finds 1, we don't care.

I was thinking about grouping on Left([Pattern],4), doing a count of the groupings filtering for records >1.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: I'm a bit confused... "if there are two or more" of what? Of the full string? Of consecutive letters within the string? Can you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: Is this a row/column structure, or just rows?  It seems like just rows.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your showing multiple rows for just a single column...  Couldn't you just trim and  look for a blank spaces?  Any blank space would indicate that you had two or move items.  Something like bleow...

```
 CHARINDEX(' ',RTRIM(LTRIM(field))) > 0
```